# change the reference passed to function in java

Tags: java

I know that we cannot change the reference passed to a function such as

```
void fun(dog a){
 a=null;
}
```

After executing the function

```
main(String[] args){

 dog a=new dog();
 fun(a);
}
```

the dog a is not changed.
So I was wondering how can we change the reference a to null inside a function

Comment: You can't do this at all. Use return values.

Comment: You need to use a wrapper object to do something to this effect

Comment: You know you cant do it but you want to know how to do it?

Comment: Alternately, use an object where `a` is a field instead of a local variable. That said, this is a pattern you should use very very sparingly - passing local variables as parameters and updating them with return values make your data flow easier to follow.

Comment: Also, please try to make code samples in your questions valid code that compiles. (Modulo boilerplate like imports or an enclosing class if your code sample is procedural.)

Comment: thx! but in case I want to return something else while changing the reference... I know it is a little bit stupid...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I delete an object passed into a Java method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591294/how-can-i-delete-an-object-passed-into-a-java-method)

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  The closest thing you can do is

```
 Dog fun(Dog a) {
   return null;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args){
   Dog a = new Dog();
   a = fun(a);
 }
```

(Among other things, this limitation can lead to less "spooky action at a distance" -- for example, a local variable reference can *only* change as the result of an explicit assignment.)

Answer (score 1):

Java is Pass by Value, where the *value of the reference* is passed, so new reference value will be passed as parameter. When this reference points to new Object inside the method, changes on reference won't reflect on the object outside of the method.

You may need to do something like below to make your outer reference to `null`.

```
Object fun(){
 return null;
}


main(String[] args){

 dog a=new dog();
 a=fun();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java is strictly a pass by value language (see [this for great info](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm)). In short, this means that, when you pass an object reference to a method, a copy of the reference is created for the method. Therefore, any thing you do to nullify the reference in the function is only nullifying the LOCAL copy of the reference variable, while the object to which it was pointing remains in memory, safe and sound.

I guess a simple analogy would be something like having two parallel streets that lead to the same building. You can destroy one of the roads, but that has no effect on the building, or the other road.